# How would I go about making a Bubblesort for this 2D string Array to sort Alphabetically?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to learn different methods of sorting for a little DB project I'm currently doing. More specifically I would like to understand how I can implement a Bubblesort for a 2D string Array to sort alphabetically as most examples I've found are single-dimension integer arrays, and involve the process of sorting by length/size.

My Array looks like this:

```
public static string[,] playerArray = new string[20, 8];
```

players are stored into the array like this:

```
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 0] = playerFirstNameBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 1] = playerIgNameBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 2] = playerSecondNameBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 3] = contactStreetBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 4] = contactTownBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 5] = contactPostcodeBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 6] = contactEmailBox.Text;
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 7] = contactTelephoneBox.Text;
```

I would like to only sort by the playerIgName

Thank you for any help and pointers.

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //[Serializable]
    public static string[,] playerArray = new string[20, 8]; // Initial player array is declared, this is where the players are stored//


    int currentIndexPlayer = 0;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    bool pastFirstZero = false;
    private string filePathName = @"C:\test.txt";
    ImageList picList = new ImageList();
    private ArrayList matches = new ArrayList(4);
    private ArrayList matchProperties = new ArrayList(6);
    string[,] sortedPlayer = new string[playerArray.GetUpperBound(0), playerArray.GetUpperBound(1)];

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        positionLabel.Text = "Current position:" + (currentIndex + 1).ToString() + "/20";
        debugLabel.Text = currentIndex.ToString();
        clearAllFields();
        LoadArray(filePathName, playerArray);
        matches = new ArrayList();
        matchProperties = new ArrayList();
        SaveArray(filePathName, playerArray);
        LoadArray(filePathName, playerArray);
        string pFirstName = playerFirstNameBox.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < playerArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {

                playerArray[i, j] = "";
            }
        }
        LoadArrayAtStart();
    }
    private void LoadArrayAtStart ()
    {
        playerFirstNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 0];
        playerIgNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 1];
        playerSecondNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 2];
        contactStreetBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 3];
        contactTownBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 4];
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 5];
        contactEmailBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 6];
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 7];
    }
    private void LoadSortedArray()
    {
        playerFirstNameBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 0];
        playerIgNameBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 1];
        playerSecondNameBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 2];
        contactStreetBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 3];
        contactTownBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 4];
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 5];
        contactEmailBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 6];
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = sortedPlayer[currentIndex, 7];
    }
    static void SaveArray(string fileName,  string[,] arr)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);

        try 
        {
            foreach (string entry in playerArray)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(entry);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't save");
            return;
        }
        writer.Close();
    } // End of SaveArray function

    static void LoadArray(string fileName, string[,] arr)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        // First try to open the file for reading

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error when reading file" +fileName);
            // Didn't work, exit method empty-handed.
        }


        // Now try to actually read the file content
        // This is the tricky bit. 
        // Note the loop-in-loop structure (i.e. a nested 'for' loop):
        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<=arr.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
                {
                    arr[i, j] = reader.ReadLine();
                    //Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j]);
                }
            }

        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not read from file " +fileName);
        }

        // Important: close the file again
        reader.Close();

    } // End of ReadArray function


    public void clearAllFields()
    {
        playerFirstNameBox.Clear();
        playerIgNameBox.Clear();
        playerSecondNameBox.Clear();
        contactStreetBox.Clear();
        contactTownBox.Clear();
        contactPostcodeBox.Clear();
        contactEmailBox.Clear();
        contactTelephoneBox.Clear();
    }

    private void addNewPlayerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (addNewPlayerBtn.Text == "Add New Player")
        {
            if (pastFirstZero == true)
            {
                currentIndex++;
            }
            if (currentIndex == 0)
            {
                pastFirstZero = true;
            }

            playerFirstNameBox.ReadOnly = false; //Unlock all fields for input//
            playerIgNameBox.ReadOnly = false;
            playerSecondNameBox.ReadOnly = false;
            contactStreetBox.ReadOnly = false;
            contactTownBox.ReadOnly = false;
            contactPostcodeBox.ReadOnly = false;
            contactEmailBox.ReadOnly = false;
            contactTelephoneBox.ReadOnly = false;

            clearAllFields();

            positionLabel.Text = "Current position:" + (currentIndex + 1).ToString() + "/20";
            debugLabel.Text = currentIndex.ToString();
            addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Confirm";
        }


        else if (addNewPlayerBtn.Text == "Confirm")
        {
            if ((playerFirstNameBox.Text != "") && (playerIgNameBox.Text != "") && (playerSecondNameBox.Text != "") && (currentIndexPlayer < 20)) // Validation check to see if all main fields were entered
            {
                string playerFirstName = playerFirstNameBox.Text;
                string playerIGName = playerFirstNameBox.Text;
                string playerSecondName = playerSecondNameBox.Text;

                for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < playerArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                    {
                        if (playerArray[i, j].Equals(playerFirstName) && (playerArray[i, j].Equals(playerIGName) && playerArray[i, j].Equals(playerSecondName)))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Player Duplicate!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); //Validation failed, display error message//
                            clearAllFields();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 0] = playerFirstNameBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 1] = playerIgNameBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 2] = playerSecondNameBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 3] = contactStreetBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 4] = contactTownBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 5] = contactPostcodeBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 6] = contactEmailBox.Text;
                playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 7] = contactTelephoneBox.Text;



                if (currentIndexPlayer < 20)
                {
                    currentIndexPlayer++;
                }
                debugLabel.Text = currentIndex.ToString();



            }
            else
            {
                if ((playerFirstNameBox.Text != "") && (playerIgNameBox.Text != "") && (playerSecondNameBox.Text != ""))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database full!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); //Validation failed, display error message//
                    addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Confirm";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fields missing!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); //Validation failed, display error message//
                    addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Confirm";
                }

            }

            addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Add New Player";

            playerFirstNameBox.ReadOnly = true; //lock all fields for input again//
            playerIgNameBox.ReadOnly = true;
            playerSecondNameBox.ReadOnly = true;
            contactStreetBox.ReadOnly = true;
            contactTownBox.ReadOnly = true;
            contactPostcodeBox.ReadOnly = true;
            contactEmailBox.ReadOnly = true;
            contactTelephoneBox.ReadOnly = true;
            SaveArray(filePathName, playerArray);

        }
    }

    private void searchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 searchForm = new Form2();
        searchForm.Show();
    }

    private void showPreviousBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex == 0)
        {
            currentIndex = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            currentIndex--;
        }
        playerFirstNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 0];
        playerIgNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 1];
        playerSecondNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 2];
        contactStreetBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 3];
        contactTownBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 4];
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 5];
        contactEmailBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 6];
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 7];

        positionLabel.Text = "Current position:" + (currentIndex + 1).ToString() + "/20";
        debugLabel.Text = currentIndex.ToString();

    }

    private void showNextBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex == 19)
        {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentIndex++;

        }

        playerFirstNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 0];
        playerIgNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 1];
        playerSecondNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 2];
        contactStreetBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 3];
        contactTownBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 4];
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 5];
        contactEmailBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 6];
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 7];

        positionLabel.Text = "Current position:" + (currentIndex + 1).ToString() + "/20";
        debugLabel.Text = currentIndex.ToString();

    }

    private void deletePlayerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playerArray[currentIndex, 0] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 1] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 2] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 3] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 4] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 5] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 6] = null;
        playerArray[currentIndex, 7] = null;

        playerFirstNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 0];
        playerIgNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 1];
        playerSecondNameBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 2];
        contactStreetBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 3];
        contactTownBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 4];
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 5];
        contactEmailBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 6];
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = playerArray[currentIndex, 7];

    }

    private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFd = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFd.Filter = "Images only. |*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.png; *.gif;";
            DialogResult rd = OpenFd.ShowDialog();
            if (rd == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                playerPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFd.FileName);
                // save the FileName to a string in your array
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You really need to learn about [classes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx). Storing player data as a two-dimensional array of strings is something that we did with FORTRAN programs in 1968. Working with a one-dimensional array or list of `Player` instances is a whole lot easier, not to mention a whole lot more understandable.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Haha, good laugh :) My project requires me to use a 2D/3D Array I'm afraid.

Comment: This post doesn't explain the steps attempted, the failures encountered, and the specific intended behavior. Because of this, I am recommending that this question be closed. If you choose to edit this post to include this content, I will retract my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic Bubblesort algorithm is the same. All that changes is the swap operation.

That is, sorting a one-dimensional array of integers is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length-1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i; j < a.Length; ++j)
    {
        if (a[i] > a[j])
        {
            // swap a[i] and a[j]
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to sort a two-dimensional array, your swap has to swap the individual fields:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetUpperBound(0)-1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i; j < a.GetUpperBound(0); ++j)
    {
        if (a[i,0] > a[j,0])
        {
            // swap a[i] and a[j]
            for (int x = 0; x < a.GetUpperBound(1); ++x)
            {
                string temp = a[i,x];
                a[i,x] = a[j,x];
                a[j,x] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```